Spring Framework beginners dilemma "@AllArgsAnnotation not working"?
I am trying to create a Bean. I have a class with only private field members with no constructor declared in springboot framework. I used an @AllArgsConstructor annotation from lombok. Now I created a config class for the previous class. While I was trying to use the constructor in the config class. It was showing exception - Expected 0 parameters but having 2. Below's the code.
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
public class Race {
    private int speed;
    private int distance;
}

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RaceConfig {
    @Bean
    public Race raceBean() {
        System.out.println("Creating a bean...");
        Race race = new Race(100, 10);
        return race;
    }
}

I have imported all the right dependencies. No dependency issue. The project is in openjdk-22. Its working without annotation by manually creating the constructor. Earlier in a different project I tried to use getTitle(), setId() methods for my program, but I dint find it in libraries through IntelliSense. I am guessing the problems could be related. I want the @AllArgsContructor annotation way to work. So any expert opinion help would be appreciated. Thank you

add @Data annotation in Race class and try once

Lombok plugin need to be correctly installed and annotations need to be enabled in the IDE. Otherwise the code for getters, setters and constructors will not be "seen" by the compiler.

Please check this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

I think you forgot to annotate raceBean with @Bean. Also, can you share the full stack trace?

Did all of the above still getting the same error. Thank you . Will appreciate any more ideas are given.

Sure annotation works, you can write a simple test like
public class AllArgsConstructorTest {

    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Race {
        private int speed;
        private int distance;
    }


    @Test
    void test() {
            System.out.println("Creating a bean...");
            Race race = new Race(100, 10);
            System.out.println(race.distance);
    }
}

Look to the log and find what class gives that error. Obviously it is not Race because Expected 0 parameters but having 4 is about something else
If this test fails look that you have dependencies in build.gradle or maven.pom
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'


my bad it's expected 0 parameter but having 2.

Actually am trying to make work @AllArgsConstructor with another project . I tried to check if it was the problem with the versioning, or the annotation itself. So I tried with a new class. And so yea it s the problem with annotation not working. So how would I resolve it now ?

By the way I tried to run the test, the same error is showing. Expected 0 but having 2 parameters. Any improvisation will be appreciated. Thank you Alex

@NihalAR I edited the answer, please look. AnnotationProcessor is important

I searched for the dependencies, among the 4 dependecies I can only find annotationProcessor in my org.projectlombok:lombok dependency. The rest of them I dont have.

Add all of them, it won't hurt

Initially I imported my lombok dependency from spring initializer website. I guess @Data class from lombok of spring initializer is bad. I installed the Lombok plugin from intelliJ marketPlace from plugins in settings. That's how I resolved it. And I got the getters and setters right this time as well. Thank you whoever tried to answer.

@AllArgsConstructor
public class Race {
    private final int speed;
    private final  int distance;
}

You can try writing it this way
